# Handling Http Errors "React"

Tags: reactjs

I am beginner in "React" and I am working on project about "Handling Http Errors". I want to show "something went wrong" when HTTP response status is 404 but it shows and error: 'response' is not defined . Why?

```
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [err, setError] = useState(null);
  const fetchMovieHandler = () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    setError(null);
    fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/film")
      .then((response) => response.json())

      .then((data) => setData(data.results.map((title) => title.title)));

    setIsLoading(false);
    if (response.status === 404) {
      throw new Error("Something Went Wrong!");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="fetch">
        <button className="fetch_btn" onClick={fetchMovieHandler}>
          Fetch Movies
        </button>
      </div>
      {!isLoading && data.length > 0 && (
        <div className="movies">
          <h3> {data[0]}</h3>
          <h3> {data[1]}</h3>
          <h3> {data[2]}</h3>
          <h3> {data[3]}</h3>
          <h3> {data[4]}</h3>
          <h3> {data[5]}</h3>
          <h3> {data[6]}</h3>
        </div>
      )}
      {isLoading && <p>Loading...</p>}
      {!isLoading && data.length === 0 && <p> Found no Movies...</p>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Your `response` is a local variable, consider storing response to a variable and trying again

Answer (score 0):

you can put the `response.status=404` inside the fetch clause because you won't have to declare response as a hook or a variable

```
 const location = useLocation();
      const [Response, setResponse] = useState('');
      const fetchMovieHandler = () => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        setError(null);
      fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/film")
        .then((response) =>{
          if (response.status === 404) {
            throw new Error("Something Went Wrong!");
          }
        }).then((data) => setData(data.results.map((title) => title.title)));
    
      setIsLoading(false);
      
      };
    
    
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="fetch">
          <button className="fetch_btn" onClick={fetchMovieHandler}>
            Fetch Movies
          </button>
        </div>
        {!isLoading && data.length > 0 && (
          <div className="movies">
            <h3> {data[0]}</h3>
            <h3> {data[1]}</h3>
            <h3> {data[2]}</h3>
            <h3> {data[3]}</h3>
            <h3> {data[4]}</h3>
            <h3> {data[5]}</h3>
            <h3> {data[6]}</h3>
          </div>
        )}
        {isLoading && <p>Loading...</p>}
        {!isLoading && data.length === 0 && <p> Found no Movies...</p>}
      </div>
    )
    
    };
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: OK i will do it